# How open new issue in YouTrack workflow script?

Tags: javascript, youtrack

I am adding new script for YouTrack for adding new issue. And after adding new issue i need to show new issue for user for editing. And i don't know how it is possible. How is it do? Maybe should i get access to common methods? But i don't know how to do it.

My script

```
/**
 * This is a template for an action rule. This rule defines a custom command
 * and the changes that are applied by the command.
 *
 * For details, read the Quick Start Guide:
 * https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/2022.2/Quick-Start-Guide-Workflows-JS.html
 */

const entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.action({
  // TODO: give the rule a human-readable title
  title: 'Create_sub_task',
  // TODO: define the custom command
  command: 'create_sub_task',
  guard: (ctx) => {
    // TODO: define the condition that must be met to enable the custom command
    return true;
  },
  action: (ctx) => {
    var issue = ctx.issue;
    
    var createIssue = function(name) {
      var newIssue = new entities.Issue(ctx.currentUser, issue.project,
        name + ' for ' + issue.summary);
      //newIssue.fields.Subsystem = subsystem;
      newIssue.fields.Type = "Detail";
      newIssue.links['subtask of'].add(issue);
      issue.links['parent for'].add(newIssue);
      newIssue.fields.Author = entities.User.current;
      // common.document.location.href = 'https://firstbiterp.youtrack.cloud/issue/FBITERP-2/IMBA';
     
      return newIssue;

    };
    
     createIssue('NewTask');

  },
  requirements: {
    // TODO: add requirements
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. The workflows run on the youtrack server, not in clients browser, and there is no support for passing such command back to client.
I believe the closest thing you can do is to show a notification with a link to the newly created issue. Look at clone as draft command, which does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this via visual Workflow Designer and a message with URL.

Workflow:

[image]